# Delay hover animation

Tags: jquery, settimeout

My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.holder').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.heading').slideUp(); 
    },function() {
        $(this).find('.heading').slideDown();
    });
});
```

Now I want to implement the `setTimeout` function. But the problem could be the `$(this)`

Comment: what do you want to delay?

Comment: if you just want to delay the slide functions, jQuery has methods for that: http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just store `$(this)` in a variable and use that variable within your anonymous function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.holder').hover(function() {
        var $self = $(this);
        setTimeout(function(){
          $self.find('.heading').slideUp(); 
        }, 500);
    },function() {
        $(this).find('.heading').slideDown();
    });
});
```

**Edit** In response to comments:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timer;
    $('.holder').hover(function() {
        var $self = $(this);
        timer = setTimeout(function(){
          timer = false;
          $self.find('.heading').slideUp(); 
        }, 2000);
    },function() {
        if(timer){
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = false;
        }else{
            $(this).find('.heading').slideDown();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: And if I want to setTimeout for .hover() ?

Comment: @user1830414 What do you mean by that? You want to delay the hover event handlers being bound after the DOM is ready?

Comment: yes, that is what I want

Comment: @user1830414 I edited it. I'm still not quite certain I understand what you want, but try that.

Comment: So that it doesn't slide up if I only hover the holder for just a second...

Comment: @user1830414 That was my first version. Just change the `500` if you want to to be longer than half a second. Try `3000` for 3 seconds.

Comment: But in the first case it slides up after a while when I just hover it for a little moment...also for `5000`. I want that the heading is sliding up only if I hover it for a view seconds.

Comment: @user1830414 Oh I see what you are saying! I'll update again.

Comment: @user1830414 You're welcome. You need to `clearTimeout`, when you want to cancel it. Hopefully my above edit is easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait for the slide down you could do like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.holder').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.heading').slideUp(); 
    },function() {
        var me = this;
        setTimeout(function() { $(me).find('.heading').slideDown(); }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

no setTimeout needed.

http://jsfiddle.net/v6pmv/

```
$(this).find('.heading').delay(1000).slideUp();
```

Answer (score 0):

In all the solutions given if the mouse passes multiple times over the hover element, the actions will cascade in an open and close freak.

Try canceling your timeout every time you hover. Example:

```
function slideHover()
{
    jqHolder = $('.holder');
    var time = jqHolder.data('time');
    if (time)
    {
        clearTimeout(time);
    }
    time = setTimeout(function() {
         jqHolder.find('.heading').slideToggle(); 
    }, jqHolder.is(':hidden') ? 0 : 500);
    jqHolder.data('time',time);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.holder').hover(slideHover, slideHover);
});
```